# Does it hold $\mathcal{O}_X (U) =\bigcap_{x \in U} \mathcal{O}_{X, x} \in K (X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm not seeing if this is true for some spaces (affines at least).

Let $K (X) = \varinjlim\limits_{\emptyset \neq U \in \text{Open}(X)} \mathcal{O}_X (U)$ be the function field for a locally ringed space (I'm specially interested in connected schemes) $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. Does $\mathcal{O}_X (U) =\bigcap_{x \in U} \mathcal{O}_{X, x} \in K (X)$  hold? If not, in general (by this I mean a class of examples), when this is true?

I know it holds for the spectrum of integral domains and affine varieties. Maybe the space must be irreducible...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $K(X)$ isn't meaningful if $X$ is not irreducible.  Actually, even if $X$ is irreducible, it is not correct; you need to restrict to non-empty $U$ (otherwise the direct limit is just equal to $\mathcal O_X(\emptyset)$, which is $0$).   Now if $X$ is not irreducible, there will be non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ whose intersection is empty, and so the direct limit over non-empty open sets won't be directed.  So you should restrict to irreducible $X$.

But if $X$ is not also reduced, then the maps $\mathcal O(U) \to K(X)$ need not be injective; there can be nilpotents that are supported on embedded components.  (Consider the ring $A := \mathbb C[x,y](xy,y^2)$, taking $U = X =$ Spec
$A$.)  So for the statement you ask about, you need to stick to schemes $X$ that
are irreducible, and have no embedded components, the most basic examples of which are integral schemes.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten to exclude $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the colimit not being filtered, what's the problem? Does my definition of $K(X)$ coincides with the sheaf of meromorphic functions or it gives something non-sense (or maybe even does not exist)? And what do you mean by embedded component?

Comment: Ok! It does not coincides with the sheaf of meromorphic functions obviously, the colimit will just be the sum over the function field of the irreducible components. Now I just don't understand what embedded component means.

Comment: @user40276: Look at the example I gave.  The global section $y$ of $\mathcal O_X$ is supported just at the origin (which in this context we call an embedded point), so it won't be detected by the function field (which is just $\mathbb C(x)$).

Comment: Ok just to confirm it . You mean the point that make the stalk have nilpotent elements? So this is equivalent to reduced. Therefore they must be reduced and irreducible, therefore integral. So the unique possibility are the integral schemes. Am I right?

Comment: @user40276: Not quite, because while any section whose support is smaller than a whole irred. comp. is nilpotent, there can be nilpotents whose support is a whole irred. component.  So something like $\mathbb C[y]/(y^2)$, or $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2)$, should be fine as well.  In commutative algebra terms, you want the property $S_1$.